# remove of child, linked to two "parents"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, one-to-many

currently i'm working on a spring project and i'm using `Hibernate 4.2.6` for persistence.
And i have a mysterious problem with deleting a child-object from two lists.

A light version of my Entity-Scheme looks like this:

```
ParentA {
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="parentA", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<Children> children;
}

ParentB {
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="parentB", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<Children> children;
}

Children {
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parenta_id", nullable=false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ParentA parentA;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parentb_id", nullable=false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ParentB parentB;
}
```

I do use JpaRepository-Interfaces for Entity-Management:

```
ParentARepository extends JpaRepository<ParentA, Long> {}
ParentBRepository extends JpaRepository<ParentB, Long> {}
ChildrenRepository extends JpaRepository<Children, Long> {}
```

But, how can i remove a Children from any of those lists with deletion in my Database?
When i call `childrenRepository.remove(children)` nothing happends. No error message, no sql-command, no log-entry. But the source around is called properly.

Hope anybody could help. I think in this case my Children-Class is more than an association-Class, but it shouldnt make a difference.

Comment: Have you tried to remove from the child from children collection of A and B parent first?

Comment: Hey, yes. Didn't work. When i try to remove by parentA.children.remove(specificChildren) ( as well as selection via index in list) and try to save afterwards via ParentARepository.save(parentA) nothing happends as well.

Comment: Do you mean you call `childrenRepository.delete(children)`?  That should be all that is needed.

Comment: are you using @Transactional on the service layer,and can you insert/delete/update elsewhere in the application ?

Comment: Hmm, i tried everything. Now i'm back to 2005 and wrote a solid query. That didnt work either! There is a @Transactional-Annotation but it got ignored i guess, because i get a javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException :/ WOOW, a hint!